# Quickblox sample error

Tags: android, quickblox

I've been trying to solve this error from the quickblox chat sample but didn't figure it out.

```
06-18 17:42:32.171: E/AndroidRuntime(17161): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-18 17:42:32.171: E/AndroidRuntime(17161): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unableto      instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.quickblox.sample.chat/com.quickblox.sample.chat.ui.activities.SplashActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.quickblox.sample.chat.ui.activities.SplashActivity" on path: /data/app/com.quickblox.sample.chat-1.apk
06-18 17:42:32.171: E/AndroidRuntime(17161):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2171)
06-18 17:42:32.171: E/AndroidRuntime(17161):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
06-18 17:42:32.171: E/AndroidRuntime(17161):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:150)
06-18 17:42:32.171: E/AndroidRuntime(17161):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
06-18 17:42:32.171: E/AndroidRuntime(17161):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-18 17:42:32.171: E/AndroidRuntime(17161):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-18 17:42:32.171: E/AndroidRuntime(17161):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
06-18 17:42:32.171: E/AndroidRuntime(17161):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-18 17:42:32.171: E/AndroidRuntime(17161):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-18 17:42:32.171: E/AndroidRuntime(17161):    at   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
06-18 17:42:32.171: E/AndroidRuntime(17161):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
06-18 17:42:32.171: E/AndroidRuntime(17161):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-18 17:42:32.171: E/AndroidRuntime(17161): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.quickblox.sample.chat.ui.activities.SplashActivity" on path: /data/app/com.quickblox.sample.chat-1.apk
06-18 17:42:32.171: E/AndroidRuntime(17161):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
06-18 17:42:32.171: E/AndroidRuntime(17161):    at  java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
06-18 17:42:32.171: E/AndroidRuntime(17161):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
06-18 17:42:32.171: E/AndroidRuntime(17161):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1071)
06-18 17:42:32.171: E/AndroidRuntime(17161):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
06-18 17:42:32.171: E/AndroidRuntime(17161):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: read this link and answer i got some thing same then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28719297/quickblox-chat-in-android-androidruntime-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-qui

Answer (score 1):

This is a related question: [Can't able to solve Class Not Found Exception with Quick Blox Sample Chat Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24285610/cant-able-to-solve-class-not-found-exception-with-quick-blox-sample-chat-exampl)

Did  you add a reference of quickblox-android-.(version number).jar in your app?

Comment: Yes , I've added it and even in the build path but didn't solve the problem